# Query optimization - Nested Loop Inner Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, optimization

So i've been having trouble optimizing the following SQL code, it currently takes up to 20 seconds to perform the query

```
SELECT t_1.UUID,
    COUNT(t_4.*) AS foo
FROM  t_1,
     t_2,
     t_3,
     t_4
WHERE t_3.RESOURCE_UUID = t_1.UUID
    AND t_1.bool_atr_1 = FALSE
    AND t_4.bool_atr_2 = TRUE
    AND t_4.STATISTIC_ID = t_3.ID
    AND t_2.ID = t_1.CLIENT_ID
    AND t_3.START_TIME BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'
    AND t_1.bool_atr_3 = FALSE
    AND t_1.bool_atr_4 = TRUE 
    GROUP  BY t_1.UUID
```

Context:

**t_3** is pretty big, around 20-30 million rows.

**t_4** is the table that represents the relation between t_1 and t_3. It is important, they join via a UUID field.

Apart from t_3 the other tables are not that big.

Now there are a lot of conditions and a time span.

[image: This is the Graphical Explanation of PgAdmin.]

The Output that I get and want just faster is 2 columns, the UUID of the resource and the count associated AS Foo for each uuid.

[image: Analysis given by pgAdmin]

Comment: What's the relationship between the tables; i.e. 1:1, 1:many?  Could you provide a small sample of the data demostrating these relationships and the expected output? One thing that caught my eye is you're doing `count(t4.*)` rather than `count(*)` which to me implies you're trying to count the number of records in table t4; but is likely a bug as you're actually counting all returned results (which could be greater than expected if the same t4 record is linked to from multiple other records)

Comment: That image is nice, but doesn't tell us anything. Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the statement.

Comment: Also, I realise you've amended your table and column names to avoid exposing schema details... but currently the SQL includes `t_1.bool_atr = TRUE` and `t_1.bool_atr = FALSE`... so you'll always get 0 results.  If representing different fields it's best to give them different names; e.g. `t_1.bool_atr1 = TRUE` and `t_1.bool_atr2 = FALSE` - to be clear when 2 names represent the same column vs different columns

Answer (score 0):

Create all the indexes as such and you are good to go:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON t_1(UUID);
CREATE INDEX index2 ON t_1(bool_atr );
CREATE INDEX index3 ON t_1(CLIENT_ID);
CREATE INDEX index4 ON t_2(ID);
CREATE INDEX index5 ON t_3(RESOURCE_UUID );
CREATE INDEX index6 ON t_4(bool_atr);
```

but I wonder why have you used both

```
    AND t_1.bool_atr = FALSE
    AND t_1.bool_atr = TRUE
```

It makes no sense..

And be aware of **read-write tradeoff** while creating indexes!!!

Comment: the bool_atr are different among themselves, its just to not show the original names